# Wake On Lan using a nic attached to a NetworkManager bridge interface

Tags: networking, networkmanager, bridge, wake-on-lan

I have been trying to set up an environment for my hypervisor, which is just a Debian Bookworm running qemu.

I have been using the web interface Cockpit to help me see things when the terminal is too arid. But in doing so, I had to switch from using `systemd-nerworkd` to `NetworkManager`.

Recently, I learned how to create a bridge network so my VMs and the host can communicate with each other. But after doing that my wakeonlan stopped working. I understand that this is expected because the router now 'sees' the MAC address of the bridge instead of the one from the nic.

From what I understand, wakeonlan works at the MAC level of the networking model. I tried using `arping` from other clients in the network and they cannot "see" the MAC address of my hypervisor (bridge).

Now I'm starting to think it might not even be possible to have a bridge at the same time as wakeonlan. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it? preferably using `NetworkManager`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wake-On-LAN is a hardware feature: it's not intended to reach the main interface participating in routing: the bridge, but always the physical interface: the actual NIC interface set as bridge port. The usual method used for Wake-On-LAN is to use the Magic Packet (original 1995 AMD white paper: [PDF](https://www.amd.com/content/dam/amd/en/documents/archived-tech-docs/white-papers/20213.pdf)), rather than other methods (such as unicast, broadcast or ARP) to avoid spurious unwanted wake ups.

Normally, Wake-On-LAN can be enabled using `ethtool` (eg: on `eth0`) with:

```
ethtool --change eth0 wol g
```

giving:

```shell
# ethtool eth0 | grep -i wake
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
```

But actually, NetworkManager, if not told otherwise, will probably disable again Wake-On-LAN on the interface it manages either before or after a suspend making it fail either the first time, or the 2nd time (and after reboots). So this is not enough. NetworkManager has to be told to use Wake-On-LAN on this interface.

`nmcli` commands below could be done using the GUI applet instead if a GUI is available.

If for example NetworkManager has these connection names: `Bridge connection 1` and as slave interface `Ethernet connection 1`, the feature has to be activated on `Ethernet connection 1`.

```shell
# nmcli connection show id 'Ethernet connection 1' | grep -i wake
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             default
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
```

which is documented in [`nm-settings-nmcli(5)`](https://networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/nm-settings-nmcli.html#nm-settings-nmcli.property.802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan):

> `802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan`
>
> The NMSettingWiredWakeOnLan options to enable. Not all devices support
> all options. May be any combination of "phy" (0x2), "unicast" (0x4),
> "multicast" (0x8), "broadcast" (0x10), "arp" (0x20), **"magic" (0x40)** or
> the special values "default" (0x1) (to use global settings) and
> "ignore" (0x8000) (to disable management of Wake-on-LAN in
> NetworkManager).

While there might be a default somewhere else, setting it explicitly to `magic` will make sure Wake-On-LAN stays enabled on this interface.

Set it to magic like this:

```
nmcli connection modify 'Ethernet connection 1' 802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan magic
```

Because this setting might not be applied immediately by NetworkManager (even including after `nmcli connection reload`) it should also be set manually, just once after having configured this, as described above (change the interface name as needed):

```
ethtool --change eth0 wol g
```

---

Now about usage. There is no reason the bridge's Ethernet MAC address will be the same as the NIC's Ethernet MAC address. This is even explicitly not the default in [modern systemd systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719379/how-can-i-make-linux-generate-different-mac-addresses-for-different-bridge-devic/719391#719391) (though NetworkManager itself might choose to copy it to the bridge). So ARP even if it's still in the cache of a system in the same LAN will never be the correct method to have a Magic Packet reach the physical interface. When suspended one can't rely the physical interface to be kept in promiscuous mode (because it's a bridge port) anymore. Anyway such ARP would also fail if the cache entry is evicted from that system's cache.

If using IP as payload mechanism, just always use a destination that will resolve into a MAC Ethernet broadcast destination (FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF) and not attempt an ARP resolution: either the LAN broadcast 255.255.255.255 or the directed broadcast (eg in LAN 192.168.1.0/24 that would be 192.168.1.255).

For example, if the NIC's MAC address is 12:34:56:78:9a:bc, using `wakeonlan`, just do, **from the same LAN**:

```
wakeonlan 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

or if the system has access to multiple LANs, eg 192.0.2.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 and the system to wake is in the latter:

```
wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

Other tools may have or lack other features. Eg: `etherwake` requires instead  to specify an interface and won't use IP but Ethernet type 0x0842 which is a de facto type reserved for Wake-On-LAN (but doesn't have to be used), and requires *root* or adequate capabilities to be used:

```
etherwake -i eth0 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

---

This is outside the scope of the question but to give pointers, wake from remote over internet requires help from the Internet gateway: it has to run custom software, or to do NAT to a broadcast and [enable routing directed broadcasts](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.6#n279) which is [always disabled by default for security reasons](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2644#section-3). As described above, setting a permanent ARP address usually doesn't help with a bridge, but it could be a *fake* permanent ARP address for the purpose of waking the system, by reserving a fictive IP address (not used anywhere, including not present on the bridge interface) in the LAN for such purpose.

Comment: Tested this on an actual physical system (running nothing fancy) that was able to be woken up before, and was still able to be woken up after configuring it with a bridge and its NIC as (single) bridge port through NetworkManager.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and for all of the in-depth explanations of how things work. I'll try this tonight.

Comment: Ah, about your last comment, fortunately I don't need over-the-internet wake-on-lan. I can do that using a VPN server I set up. But it is always good to know more about a particular technology. Thanks again.

Comment: It all works beautifully! Thanks. I think I was missing the command from ethtool and NetworkManager was not saving the config on reboot or something. :)